# How to render/fetch a template remotely through StimulusJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

So following is the bit of code that I'd like to add in the HTML after a particular event occurs:

```
<div class='comment-form' data-controller='comment'>                        
  <form action='' data-action='comment#createComment'>                    
    <div class='comment-form__title'>Add your reply:</div>                
    <textarea class='comment-form__textarea' placeholder='Type in your reply' data-comment-target='commentText'></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class='btn-secondary' >           
  </form>
</div>
```

As of now, the only way I could find, is the following:

```
  post.insertAdjacentHTML(`<div class='comment-form' data-controller='comment'>                        
  <form action='' data-action='comment#createComment'><div class='comment-form__title'>Add your reply:</div><textarea class='comment-form__textarea' placeholder='Type in your reply' data-comment-target='commentText'></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit" class='btn-secondary'></form></div>`)
```

I'm looking for a way where this template is rendered through the server code(read: Rails), instead of me hardcoding it in the JS.

P.S:

As of writing this, Discourse for StimulusJS is down, and I could find a link for a question similar to what I'm asking here: https://discourse.stimulusjs.org/t/fetching-a-partial-on-click/1297, and on Stackoverflow, I couldn't find a relevant question to this.

Answer (score 2):

If you looking to render the comment form continuously. You can use the loop like this:

```
 <div class='post-comments-section'>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <div class="post-comments">
        <p>
          <b><%= comment.user.name %>:</b> <%= comment.content %>
        </p>
        <span> <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") %> </span>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= form_for(post.comments.new, url: post_comments_path(post)) do |form| %>
      <%= form.text_field :content, id: :comment_content, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Add new Comment' %>
      <%= form.submit 'Comment', class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

And, If you are looking to add something specific. You can add the partial from the controller with a condition.

```
def create
  if comment.create 
    render partial: "posts/comment"
  end
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to submit the form remotely. I would like to override this and inject my own logic there through StimulusJS.